# SQL query conditioned by error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
select "ID" =
CASE
    WHEN LEN(LEFT(ID, (charindex('.', ID)-1))) > 1 THEN LEFT(ID, (charindex('.', ID)-1))
    ELSE ID
END
From table
where tableID = '111'
```

The ID is something like AA11.1 or BB22 some with a period and some without. I'm wanting to truncate all characters after the period, but in the case where there is no period it errors. I want to keep what is there for an ID without a period.

So for AA11.1 I want to return AA11 and for BB22 I want to return BB22.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
CASE
    WHEN charindex('.', ID) > 1 THEN LEFT(ID, (charindex('.', ID)-1))
    ELSE ID
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select ID =  
CASE WHEN charindex('.', ID) > 1 THEN LEFT(ID, (charindex('.', ID)-1))
    ELSE ID
END
```

Comment: Essentially the same as @albe. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

You I would do it as follows.

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(10) = 'AA110'
SELECT LEFT(@test, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @test) = 0 THEN LEN(@test)
                        ELSE CHARINDEX('.', @test) - 1
                   END);


SET @test = 'AA110.12'
SELECT LEFT(@test, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', @test) = 0 THEN LEN(@test)
                        ELSE CHARINDEX('.', @test) - 1
                   END);
```

Comment: Yes, except that errors when the value of the test variable is 'AA112'. Some of my IDs have a period and some do not. The tableID changes and can return an ID that does not have a period.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler query will be

```
SELECT IF('AA11.1' LIKE '%.%', LEFT('AA11.1', LOCATE('.','AA11.1')-1), 'AA11.1') AS tmp
```

so for you it will be

```
SELECT IF(ID LIKE '%.%', LEFT(ID, LOCATE('.',ID)-1), ID)
From table
where tableID = '111'
```

What it does is

- Check if ID contains a `.`
- If yes then it uses LEFT.
- If not then it uses the ID itself.

---

As I missed that the TS asked for sql-server query, If anyone is looking for such query on MySQL the above example should work. As for sql-server the other answers and the modified query of the TS on the comment of this answer should also help. Good luck.

Comment: I am using LEFT above. The problem is that when using left and having a string that does not contain a '.' returns an error since the length returned is invalid. This is an issue with SUBSTRING as well.

Comment: @BradGermain yes, but you are also using `CHARINDEX` try `LOCATE`. But I am updating my answer as of the moment. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response and explanation. I'm getting an error with this however... Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' and near ','

Comment: @BradGermain see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/22129). you are most welcome.

Comment: Ah I see. It is most likely because you are testing in MySQL. I'm using SQL Server. I modified it a little and got it to work: SELECT CASE
  WHEN ID LIKE '%.%' THEN LEFT(ID, CHARINDEX('.',ID)-1)
  ELSE ID
END
From table
where tableID = '111'

Comment: Ah, I see. That was my mistake.